# How to set numbers with commas in table Latex

Tags: latex

I tried several times to adjust the table in a way that the number in the 3rd column would be 3,025 instead of 3025 (without the comma) but without any success. Do you have any idea how to fix this? I tried removing \num{} but it still gives me the number without being separated by the comma. 
Thanks

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % 
    \usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \newcommand{\undepth}[1]{%
        \smash[b]{%
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}#1\end{varwidth}
        }%
    }
    \usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{
            c
            S[table-format=6]
            S[table-format=4]
            S[table-format=4]
            S[table-format=6]
        }
        \toprule        
        \makecell{date} & {col2} & {col3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{\% \\ col}} & {Total} \\
        \midrule
        1999 & 31530 & 904   & \num{2.55} & 22854 \\
        2000 & 56551 & 813   & \num{2.55} & 23004 \\
        \midrule
        Sum (not-real)  & 105212 & \num{3025} &  \num{2.54} & 100250 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally group separators are only inserted in numbers with at least 5 digits. To enable this for numbers with fewer digits, you can use `group-minimum-digits=4`

Furthermore the format for the second to last column should be `1.2` instead of `4`

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % 
    \usepackage[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \newcommand{\undepth}[1]{%
        \smash[b]{%
            \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}#1\end{varwidth}
        }%
    }
    \usepackage{makecell}%To keep spacing of text in tables

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{
            c
            S[table-format=6]
            S[table-format=4]
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=6]
        }
        \toprule        
        \makecell{date} & {col2} & {col3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{\% \\ col}} & {Total} \\
        \midrule
        1999 & 31530 & 904   & 2.55 & 22854 \\
        2000 & 56551 & 813   & 2.55 & 23004 \\
        \midrule
        Sum (not-real)  & 105212 & 3025 &  2.54 & 100250 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]